# No Hot water to Shower and Taps furthest away from hot water tank

Tags: water, water-heater, heat-pump

I have this setup coming off of my hot water tank.

Recently I started getting only luke warm water to the taps and shower furthest away from the water heater(#9 & #10), also sometimes my cold taps would run warm.  The taps and showers closest did not have this issue. I cannot seem to find a recirculating pump or any sort of mixing valves in the system. This issue only started once I installed new filters into the Filtration system. Is it possible to have this system without a mixing valve/recirculating pump?

[image]

Comment: Sorry forgot to connect the cold supply to all of the taps!

Comment: Does the hot really form a closed loop as shown in the drawing? If so, each fixture will draw water from both ends of the loop. Then #1 would draw most of its supply from the water heater hot and a little of its supply from the cold. The ratio would progress toward cold up to #10 where most supply would come from the cold and a little from the hot. It seems odd that there would exist a hot loop without any pump to force water to go the right direction - maybe it should have a pump, but the pump has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

1) The red line that is teed into the blue line after the check valve could be used as a recirculating line to provide almost instant hot water to all the hot faucets. Make sure that you add a check valve in that line so you do not get reverse water flow when a faucet is turned on. 2) The supply line to the heat pump should come from the bottom of the storage tank so it utilizes the coldest water to be heated,  and not come off the hot supply from the storage tank.  3)The hot discharge from the heat pump should go to a separate tap near the middle of the tank if one is available. If a separate tapping  connection point is not available I would then tee it into the cold blue line at the tank supply but after the check valve. 4) I believe that a circulation pump is required in the heat pump line sized as per the heat pump's instruction sheet. 5) One last thing, if the red line I mentioned in item #1 is for a  recirculating line to insure almost instant hot water at each faucet it can stay as is and you will need to install a pump  on that line to circulate the water (buy the smallest pump you can) Mine is a B&G NBF-8S  103257LF 39 watts. 6) you said that you did not show the cold supply (mistake).